# Проблема с Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Получаю данные из Firebase. Есть карточки статей и как мне открыть именно ту статью на которую я кликнул (у меня пост открывает одну и ту же статью)?

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { getDocs, collection, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { auth, db } from "../firebase-config";
    import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
    import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
    import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
    import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
    import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
    import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    function BlogCard({ isAuth }) {
          const [postLists, setPostList] = useState([]);
          const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "post");
          
          
          const deletePost = async (id) => {
                const postDoc = doc(db, "post", id);
                await deleteDoc(postDoc);
          };
    
          useEffect(() => {
                const getPosts = async () => {
                      const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
                      setPostList(
                            data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })),
                            );
                      };
                
                getPosts();
    
          }, [deletePost]);
          
    
          return (
                <div
                className="blog"
                style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      flexWrap: "wrap",
                }}
                >
                {postLists.map((post, id) => { 
                      return (
                            <Card className="card" sx={{borderRadius: "20px", backgroundColor: "#f8f5ee"}} key={id
                            }>
                                                    <CardMedia 
                                                          sx={{
                                                                transition: "0.3s",
                                                                ":hover": {
                                                                      transform:
                                                                            "scale(1.1)",
                                                                },
                                                                cursor: "pointer",
                                                                backgroundRepeat:
                                                                      "no-repeat",
                                                                backgroundSize: "contain",
                                                                borderRadius: "20px",
    
                                                          }}
                                                          component="img"
                                                          alt="Фото отсутсвует"
                                                          height="180"
                                                          image={post.photoLink}
                                                    />
                                             
                                     
        
                                        <CardContent className="cardContent">
                                              <Typography className="title"  
                                                    gutterBottom
                                                    variant="h5"
                                                    component="div"
                                                    sx={{cursor: "pointer"}}
                                              >
                                                    {post.title.length > 55 ? (post.title.substr(0, 55 )) + "..." : post.title}
                                                    
                                              </Typography>
                                              <Typography
                                                    variant="body2"
                                                    color="#010001"
                                              >
                                                  
                                                       {post.postText.length > 150 ? (post.postText.substr(0, 150)) + "..." : post.postText}
                                                          <span className="moreText" >
                                                                {post.postText.slice(150)}
                                                          </span>
                                                  
                                              </Typography>
                                        </CardContent>
    
    
                                        <CardActions className="cardAction" >
                                              <div className="author-date">
                                                    <Button sx={{p: 0, ml: 2, fontSize: "11px"}} className="author" size="small">
                                                          {post.author.name}
                                                    </Button>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <Button sx={{p: 0, ml: 2, fontSize: "12px"}} className="date" size="small">
                                                          {post.postDate}
                                                    </Button>
                                              </div>
    
                                              <Link to="/myposts" className="moreBtn" onClick={() => {readMore(id)}}>Больше
                                                    <i className="fa-solid fa-arrow-up arrow"></i>
                                              </Link>
                                              
                                              <div className="delete">
    
                                                    {isAuth && post.author.id ===
                                                                auth.currentUser
                                                                .uid && (
                                                                      <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"
                                                                      onClick={() => {
                                                                            deletePost(
                                                                                  post.id
                                                                                  );
                                                                            }}
                                                                            >
                                                                      {" "}
                                                                </i>
                                                          )}
                                              </div>
                                           
                                        </CardActions>
                                  </Card>
                            );
                      })}
                </div>
          );
    }     
    
    export default BlogCard
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]